# Check array to see if it contains one of the two specified values

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I need help with figuring out whether an array contains strings other than two specific strings. For example, if a string has anything other than "a", it should fail. Case sensitivity is not important.

```
var array = ["a", "a", "a", "b"]; // this should fail
var array2 = ["a", "a", "a", "a"]; // this should pass
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var abFound = false;
// Run a for loop and look for the contents of the array element (indexOf) to see if it equals "a" or "b", if it does set abFound to true.
```

Any suggestions or better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Loop over the array and the moment you see anything other than `"a"` `return false`? Doesn't sound complicated.

Comment: Is this your homework for a class?

Answer (score 2):

The function [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used to iterate over an array, testing each element of that array against a supplied predicate, and *returning `true` as soon as the predicate returns `true`*.

```
var not_A = array.some(function(s) {
   return s !== 'a';
});
```

If the predicate returns `false` for every element in the array then the eventual return value of `.some` is also `false`.

You can also use `Array.prototype.every` which has the opposite behaviour - it returns `false` as soon as any predicate test fails, and only returns `true` if the predicate returns `true` for *every* element of the array:

```
var all_A = array.every(function(s) {
    return s === 'a';
});
```

Using `Array.prototype.filter` is inefficient, since it is required to test every single element in the array with no opportunity to terminate early as soon as a contra-indicating result is found.

Answer (score 0):

Filter based on the element not being equal to whatever you are checking for, and check if it's length is 0.

```
var not_a = array.filter(function(value) { return value != 'a' }).length != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var filtered = array.filter(function(value){
return value === 'a';
 });
if(filtered.length === array.length){
console.log("pass")
} else{
console.log("fail")
}
```

Comment: same comment as to dave - please learn your ES5 functions.  This would be more effectively achieved using `Array.prototype.every`.